# How to manually disable or hide the system bar (menu bar) at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, system, user-interface

I am using an ASUS Transformer TF300 with Android 4.1.1, and there is an app that shows the playing cards at the bottom of the screen, and show the "Continue" button when the card game is finished.

But the playing cards are half hidden by the system bar, and this "Continue" button is hidden by the system bar mostly, except about 2mm is showing, so it is kind of difficult to press the button.

Is there a way to tell the system bar / menu bar to hide itself?  I also went to the settings and set the "System bar lock" to off, but somehow the bar is still showing.

Comment: Its a bug in the application, it should know the difference between the "soft" height and the physical height.  (Or in Android, if you want to blame the platform for making bugs in applications like this possible).  Sometimes rotating your device may work better (the layout bug may be less noticable, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this system bar is part of Android, and is used when the device doesn't have any hardware buttons to press.

As such, it cannot be hidden.

It shouldn't, however, impact upon gameplay - this is an issue with the app, and you should contact the app developer to have it fixed.

Comment: hm... I wonder... it seems like a popular game and it looks high resolution to be a 10 inch tablet game... and the TF300 is fairly standard 1280 x 800... so I wonder why the game is designed such a way...

Comment: I also wonder would it make sense if Android somehow let the double click (or even single short click) of the Power button let the system bar slide out, and slide away after 5 or 10 seconds...

Answer (score 2):

Some Custom Rom's have a feature which will disable Navigation Bar and Status Bar, one well-known is ParanoidAndroid with it's feature "Expanded Desktop".

Apart from that I don't know about any other ways to hide the navigation bar.

New CyanogenMod-Versions will also contain this functionality: https://plus.google.com/u/0/117962666888533781522/posts/dYSseZeQ8Sf